# How to remove white space around Slideshow Web Part (2013)?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have beginner experience with HTML and CSS but haven't been coding for awhile. I added a Picture Library and there is a significant amount of empty white space to the right that I can't remove. I have tried so many different things, and I'm chalking up to me probably missing something. I've Edited the source and removed all &#160 instances, and also have gone into SP Designer and removed &nbsp and nothing changed. I'm not sure how to access the CSS style sheet.[image: I've attached an image of what it looks like.]

I've also attached the entire code for the site. Please let me know if there's a solution for this issue.

Thank you.

```
<%@Master language="C#"%>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="Welcome" src="~/_controltemplates/15/Welcome.ascx" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<SharePoint:SPHtmlTag dir="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_direction_dir_value%>" ID="SPHtmlTag" runat="server" >
<head runat="server">

</head>
<body>
  <SharePoint:ImageLink runat="server"/>
  <SharePoint:SPNoScript runat="server"/>
  <SharePoint:SPClientIDGenerator runat="server" ServerControlID="DeltaPlaceHolderMain;DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea;DeltaPlaceHolderUtilityContent" />
  <SharePoint:SharePointForm runat="server" onsubmit="if (typeof(_spFormOnSubmitWrapper) != 'undefined') {return _spFormOnSubmitWrapper();} else {return true;}">
    <script type="text/javascript"> var submitHook = function () { return false; }; theForm._spOldSubmit = theForm.submit; theForm.submit = function () { if (!submitHook()) { this._spOldSubmit(); } }; </script>
    <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaSPWebPartManager" runat="server">
        <WebPartPages:SPWebPartManager runat="Server"/>
    </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
    <asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="false" EnablePartialRendering="true" EnableScriptGlobalization="false" EnableScriptLocalization="true" />
    <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaDelegateControls" runat="server">
        <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="GlobalNavigation" />
        <SharePoint:DelegateControl ControlId="GlobalSiteLink3" Scope="Farm" runat="server" Visible="false" />
    </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
<div id="TurnOnAccessibility" style="display:none" class="s4-notdlg noindex">
    <a id="linkTurnOnAcc" href="#" class="ms-accessible ms-acc-button" onclick="SetIsAccessibilityFeatureEnabled(true);UpdateAccessibilityUI();document.getElementById('linkTurnOffAcc').focus();return false;">
    <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,master_turnonaccessibility%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/></a>
</div>
<div id="TurnOffAccessibility" style="display:none" class="s4-notdlg noindex">
    <a id="linkTurnOffAcc" href="#" class="ms-accessible ms-acc-button" onclick="SetIsAccessibilityFeatureEnabled(false);UpdateAccessibilityUI();document.getElementById('linkTurnOnAcc').focus();return false;">
    <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,master_turnoffaccessibility%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/></a>
</div>
<div class="s4-notdlg s4-skipribbonshortcut noindex">
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('startNavigation').focus();" class="ms-accessible ms-acc-button" accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,skipribbon_accesskey%>" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,skipRibbonCommandsLink%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/></a>
</div>
<div class="s4-notdlg noindex">
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('mainContent').focus();" class="ms-accessible ms-acc-button" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,mainContentLink%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/></a>
</div>
<div id="TurnOffAnimation" style="display:none;" class="s4-notdlg noindex">
    <a id="linkTurnOffAnimation" href="#" class="ms-accessible ms-acc-button" onclick="ToggleAnimationStatus();return false;">
    <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,master_disableanimation%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/></a>
</div>
<div id="TurnOnAnimation" style="display:none;" class="s4-notdlg noindex">
    <a id="linkTurnOnAnimation" href="#" class="ms-accessible ms-acc-button" onclick="ToggleAnimationStatus();return false;">
    <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,master_enableanimation%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/></a>
</div>
<a id="HiddenAnchor" href="javascript:;" style="display:none;"></a>
<div id="suiteBar" class="ms-dialogHidden noindex">
    <div id="suiteBarLeft">
        <div class="ms-table ms-fullWidth">
            <div class="ms-tableRow">
                <div class="ms-tableCell ms-verticalAlignMiddle">
                    <SharePoint:DelegateControl id="ID_SuiteBarBrandingDelegate" ControlId="SuiteBarBrandingDelegate" runat="server"/>
                </div>
                <SharePoint:AjaxDelta runat="server" id="DeltaSuiteLinks" BlockElement="true" CssClass="ms-core-deltaSuiteLinks">
                        <div id="suiteLinksBox">
                            <SharePoint:DelegateControl id="ID_SuiteLinksDelegate" ControlId="SuiteLinksDelegate" runat="server" />
                        </div>
                </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="suiteBarRight">
        <SharePoint:AjaxDelta runat="server" id="DeltaSuiteBarRight" CssClass="ms-core-deltaSuiteBarRight" BlockElement="true">
                <div id="welcomeMenuBox">
  <wssuc:Welcome id="IdWelcome" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" />
                </div>
                <div id="suiteBarButtons">
                       <span class="ms-siteactions-root" id="siteactiontd">
                       <SharePoint:SiteActions runat="server" accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,tb_SiteActions_AK%>" id="SiteActionsMenuMain"
                        PrefixHtml=""
                        SuffixHtml=""
                        ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23"
                        ThemeKey="spcommon"
                        MenuAlignment="Right"
                        MenuNotVisibleHtml="&amp;nbsp;"
                        LargeIconMode="false"
                        >

                        <CustomTemplate>
                        <SharePoint:FeatureMenuTemplate runat="server"
                            FeatureScope="Site"
                            Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
                            GroupId="SiteActions"
                            UseShortId="true"
                            >
                          <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server"
                              id="MenuItem_ShareThisSite"
                              Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_sharethissite%>"
                              Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_sharethissitedescription%>"
                              MenuGroupId="100"
                              Sequence="110"
                              UseShortId="true"
                              PermissionsString="ViewPages"
                              PermissionMode="Any" />
                          <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_EditPage"
                              Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_editpage15%>"
                              Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_editpagedescriptionv4%>"
                              ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/ActionsEditPage.png?rev=23"
                              MenuGroupId="200"
                              Sequence="210"
                              PermissionsString="EditListItems"
                              ClientOnClickNavigateUrl="javascript:ChangeLayoutMode(false);" />
                          <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_CreatePage"
                              Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_addpage15%>"
                              Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_createpagedesc%>"
                              ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/NewContentPageHH.png?rev=23"
                              MenuGroupId="200"
                              Sequence="220"
                              UseShortId="true"
                              ClientOnClickScriptContainingPrefixedUrl="OpenCreateWebPageDialog('~siteLayouts/createwebpage.aspx')"
                              PermissionsString="AddListItems, EditListItems"
                              PermissionMode="All" />
                          <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_Create"
                              Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_addapp15%>"
                              Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_createdesc%>"
                              MenuGroupId="200"
                              Sequence="230"
                              UseShortId="true"
                              ClientOnClickScriptContainingPrefixedUrl="GoToPage('~siteLayouts/addanapp.aspx')"
                              PermissionsString="ManageLists, ManageSubwebs"
                              PermissionMode="Any" />
                          <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_ViewAllSiteContents"
                              Text="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_15%>"
                              Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_allcontentdescription%>"
                              ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/allcontent32.png?rev=23"
                              MenuGroupId="200"
                              Sequence="240"
                              UseShortId="true"
                              ClientOnClickNavigateUrl="~siteLayouts/viewlsts.aspx"
                              PermissionsString="ViewFormPages"
                              PermissionMode="Any" />
                          <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_ChangeTheLook"
                              Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_changethelook15%>"
                              Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_changethelookdesc15%>"
                              MenuGroupId="300"
                              Sequence="310"
                              UseShortId="true"
                              ClientOnClickNavigateUrl="~siteLayouts/designgallery.aspx"
                              PermissionsString="ApplyThemeAndBorder,ApplyStyleSheets,Open,ViewPages,OpenItems,ViewListItems"
                              PermissionMode="All" />
                          <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_Settings"
                              Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_settings15%>"
                              Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_sitesettingsdescriptionv4%>"
                              ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/settingsIcon.png?rev=23"
                              MenuGroupId="300"
                              Sequence="320"
                              UseShortId="true"
                              ClientOnClickScriptContainingPrefixedUrl="GoToPage('~siteLayouts/settings.aspx')"
                              PermissionsString="EnumeratePermissions,ManageWeb,ManageSubwebs,AddAndCustomizePages,ApplyThemeAndBorder,ManageAlerts,ManageLists,ViewUsageData"
                              PermissionMode="Any" />
                          <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_SwitchToMobileView"
                              Visible="false"
                              Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_switchtomobileview%>"
                              Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_switchtomobileviewdesc%>"
                              MenuGroupId="300"
                              Sequence="330"
                              UseShortId="true"
                              ClientOnClickScript="var mswlh = window.location.href; if (mswlh.indexOf('?')==-1) { window.location = mswlh + '?mobile=1'; } else { window.location = mswlh + '&mobile=1'; }" />
                        </SharePoint:FeatureMenuTemplate>
                        </CustomTemplate>
                      </SharePoint:SiteActions></span>
<span id="ms-help">
    <SharePoint:ThemedClusteredHoverImage
        runat="server"
        ID="TopHelpLink"
        ThemeKey="spintl"
        TouchMode="true"
        TouchModeWidth="30"
        TouchModeHeight="30"
        TouchModePaddingTop="7"
        TouchModePaddingRight="7"
        TouchModePaddingBottom="7"
        TouchModePaddingLeft="7"
        ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/~lcid/images/spintl.png"
        Width="16"
        Height="16"
        OffsetX="19"
        OffsetY="1"
        HoverOffsetX="1"
        HoverOffsetY="1"
        NavigateUrl="#"
        onclick="TopHelpButtonClick('HelpHome',event);return false"
        AlternateText="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_helplink_text%>"
        AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_helplink_accesskey%>"
        ToolTip="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_helplink_text%>" />
</span>
                </div>
        </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
    </div>
</div>
        <div id="ms-hcTest"></div>
        <div id="s4-ribbonrow">
        <div id="globalNavBox" class="noindex">
<div id="ribbonBox">
    <div id="s4-ribboncont">
        <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaSPRibbon" BlockElement="true" runat="server">
            <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ID="GlobalDelegate0" ControlId="GlobalSiteLink0" />
            <SharePoint:SPRibbon
                runat="server"
                PlaceholderElementId="RibbonContainer"
                CssFile="" >

                <SharePoint:SPRibbonPeripheralContent
                    runat="server"
                    CssClass="ms-core-defaultFont ms-dialogHidden"
                    Location="TabRowLeft">
                </SharePoint:SPRibbonPeripheralContent>
                <SharePoint:SPRibbonPeripheralContent
                    runat="server"
                    Location="TabRowRight"
                    ID="RibbonTabRowRight"
                    CssClass="s4-trc-container s4-notdlg ms-core-defaultFont">
                    <SharePoint:SPSharePromotedActionButton runat="server"/>
                    <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="PromotedActions" AllowMultipleControls="true" />
                    <SharePoint:SPSyncPromotedActionButton runat="server"/>
                    <SharePoint:PageStateActionButton id="PageStateActionButton" runat="server" Visible="false" />
<span id="fullscreenmodebox" class="ms-qatbutton">
    <span id="fullscreenmode">
        <SharePoint:ThemedClusteredHoverImage
            runat="server"
            ID="fullscreenmodeBtn"
            ThemeKey="spcommon"
            TouchMode="true"
            TouchModeWidth="30"
            TouchModeHeight="30"
            TouchModePaddingLeft="7"
            TouchModePaddingTop="7"
            TouchModePaddingRight="7"
            TouchModePaddingBottom="7"
            ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23"
            Width="16"
            Height="16"
            OffsetX="143"
            OffsetY="178"
            HoverOffsetX="125"
            HoverOffsetY="178"
            NavigateUrl="#"
            onclick="SetFullScreenMode(true);PreventDefaultNavigation();return false;"
            AlternateText="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_fullscreenmodelinkalt_text%>"
            ToolTip="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_fullscreenmodelinkalt_text%>"
            />
    </span>
    <span id="exitfullscreenmode" style="display: none;">
        <SharePoint:ThemedClusteredHoverImage
            runat="server"
            ID="exitfullscreenmodeBtn"
            ThemeKey="spcommon"
            TouchMode="true"
            TouchModeWidth="30"
            TouchModeHeight="30"
            TouchModePaddingLeft="7"
            TouchModePaddingTop="7"
            TouchModePaddingRight="7"
            TouchModePaddingBottom="7"
            ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23"
            Width="16"
            Height="16"
            OffsetX="107"
            OffsetY="178"
            HoverOffsetX="179"
            HoverOffsetY="96"
            NavigateUrl="#"
            onclick="SetFullScreenMode(false);PreventDefaultNavigation();return false;"
            AlternateText="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_fullscreenmodelinkalt_text%>"
            ToolTip="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_fullscreenmodelinkalt_text%>"
            />
    </span>
</span>
<SharePoint:DeveloperDashboard runat="server" />
<SharePoint:DeveloperDashboardLauncher
    ID="DeveloperDashboardLauncher"
    ThemeKey="spcommon"
    TouchMode="true"
    TouchModeWidth="30"
    TouchModeHeight="30"
    TouchModePaddingLeft="7"
    TouchModePaddingTop="7"
    TouchModePaddingRight="7"
    TouchModePaddingBottom="7"
    NavigateUrl="javascript:return false"
    OnClick="ToggleDeveloperDashboard(window.g_ddHostBase);return false"
    OuterCssClass="ms-dd-button ms-qatbutton"
    runat="server"
    ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23"
    AlternateText="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_launchdevdashalt_text%>"
    ToolTip="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_launchdevdashalt_text%>"
    OffsetX="145"
    OffsetY="196"
    HoverOffsetX="163"
    HoverOffsetY="196"
    Height="16"
    Width="16" />
                </SharePoint:SPRibbonPeripheralContent>
            </SharePoint:SPRibbon>
        </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
    </div>
    <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaSPNavigation" runat="server">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="SPNavigation" runat="server">
            <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="PublishingConsole" Id="PublishingConsoleDelegate" />
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
</div>
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaWebPartAdderUpdatePanelContainer" BlockElement="true" CssClass="ms-core-webpartadder" runat="server">
  <div id="WebPartAdderUpdatePanelContainer">
    <asp:UpdatePanel
        ID="WebPartAdderUpdatePanel"
        UpdateMode="Conditional"
        ChildrenAsTriggers="false"
        runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>
        <WebPartPages:WebPartAdder ID="WebPartAdder" runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
      <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="WebPartAdder" />
    </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
  </div>
</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="s4-workspace" class="ms-core-overlay">
        <div id="s4-bodyContainer">
        <div id="s4-titlerow"
            class="ms-dialogHidden s4-titlerowhidetitle">
        <div id="titleAreaBox"
            class="ms-noList ms-table ms-core-tableNoSpace">
        <div id="titleAreaRow"
            class="ms-tableRow">
<div id="siteIcon" class="ms-tableCell ms-verticalAlignTop">
    <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaSiteLogo" BlockElement="true" runat="server">
        <SharePoint:SPSimpleSiteLink CssClass="ms-siteicon-a" runat="server" id="onetidProjectPropertyTitleGraphic" >

            <SharePoint:SiteLogoImage CssClass="ms-siteicon-img" name="onetidHeadbnnr0" id="onetidHeadbnnr2" LogoImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/siteIcon.png?rev=23" runat="server"/>
        </SharePoint:SPSimpleSiteLink>
    </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
</div>
            <div class="ms-breadcrumb-box ms-tableCell ms-verticalAlignTop">
                <div
                    class="ms-breadcrumb-top">
<div class="ms-breadcrumb-dropdownBox" style="display:none;">
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaBreadcrumbDropdown" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:PopoutMenu
        Visible="false"
        runat="server"
        ID="GlobalBreadCrumbNavPopout"
        IconUrl="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23"
        IconAlt="<%$Resources:wss,master_breadcrumbIconAlt%>"
        ThemeKey="v15breadcrumb"
        IconOffsetX="215"
        IconOffsetY="120"
        IconWidth="16"
        IconHeight="16"
        AnchorCss="ms-breadcrumb-anchor"
        AnchorOpenCss="ms-breadcrumb-anchor-open"
        MenuCss="ms-breadcrumb-menu ms-noList">

        <div class="ms-breadcrumb-top">
            <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="ms-breadcrumb-header" Text="<%$Resources:wss,master_breadcrumbHeader%>" />
        </div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb" runat="server">
        <SharePoint:ListSiteMapPath
                runat="server"
                SiteMapProviders="SPSiteMapProvider,SPContentMapProvider"
                RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="false"
                PathSeparator=""
                CssClass="ms-breadcrumb"
                NodeStyle-CssClass="ms-breadcrumbNode"
                CurrentNodeStyle-CssClass="ms-breadcrumbCurrentNode"
                RootNodeStyle-CssClass="ms-breadcrumbRootNode"
                NodeImageOffsetX="217"
                NodeImageOffsetY="210"
                NodeImageWidth="16"
                NodeImageHeight="16"
                NodeImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23"
                RTLNodeImageOffsetX="199"
                RTLNodeImageOffsetY="210"
                RTLNodeImageWidth="16"
                RTLNodeImageHeight="16"
                RTLNodeImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23"
                HideInteriorRootNodes="true"
                SkipLinkText="" />
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </SharePoint:PopoutMenu>
</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
</div>
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaTopNavigation" BlockElement="true" CssClass="ms-displayInline ms-core-navigation" role="navigation" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="TopNavigationDataSource" Id="topNavigationDelegate">

        <Template_Controls>
            <asp:SiteMapDataSource
                ShowStartingNode="False"
                SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider"
                id="topSiteMap"
                runat="server"
                StartingNodeUrl="sid:1002"/>
        </Template_Controls>
    </SharePoint:DelegateControl>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTopNavBar" runat="server">
        <SharePoint:AspMenu
            ID="TopNavigationMenu"
            Runat="server"
            EnableViewState="false"
            DataSourceID="topSiteMap"
            AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%>"
            UseSimpleRendering="true"
            UseSeparateCss="false"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            StaticDisplayLevels="2"
            AdjustForShowStartingNode="true"
            MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="2"
            SkipLinkText="" />
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
                </div>
<h1 id="pageTitle" class="ms-core-pageTitle">
  <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
        <SharePoint:SPTitleBreadcrumb
              runat="server"
              RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="true"
                  SiteMapProvider="SPContentMapProvider"
              CentralAdminSiteMapProvider="SPXmlAdminContentMapProvider">
        <PATHSEPARATORTEMPLATE>
          <SharePoint:ClusteredDirectionalSeparatorArrow runat="server" />
        </PATHSEPARATORTEMPLATE>
      </SharePoint:SPTitleBreadcrumb>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
  <SharePoint:AjaxDelta BlockElement="true" id="DeltaPlaceHolderPageDescription" CssClass="ms-displayInlineBlock ms-normalWrap" runat="server">
    <a href="javascript:;" id="ms-pageDescriptionDiv" style="display:none;">
      <span id="ms-pageDescriptionImage"></span>
    </a>
    <span class="ms-accessible" id="ms-pageDescription">
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageDescription" runat="server" />
    </span>
    <SharePoint:ScriptBlock runat="server">

      _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("setupPageDescriptionCallout");
    </SharePoint:ScriptBlock>
  </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="ms-tableCell ms-verticalAlignTop">
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderSearchArea" BlockElement="true" CssClass="ms-mpSearchBox ms-floatRight" runat="server">
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSearchArea" runat="server">
    <div id="searchInputBox">
      <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="SmallSearchInputBox" />
    </div>
  </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="contentRow">
<div id="sideNavBox"
     class="ms-dialogHidden ms-forceWrap ms-noList">
  <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar" BlockElement="true" CssClass="ms-core-navigation" role="navigation" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBar" runat="server">
                <a id="startNavigation" name="startNavigation" tabIndex="-1"></a>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBarTop" runat="server" />
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderQuickLaunchTop" runat="server" />
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBarDataSource" runat="server" />
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderCalendarNavigator" runat="server" />
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftActions" runat="server" />
                <div class="ms-core-sideNavBox-removeLeftMargin">
                <SharePoint:SPNavigationManager
                    id="QuickLaunchNavigationManager"
                    runat="server"
                    QuickLaunchControlId="V4QuickLaunchMenu"
                    ContainedControl="QuickLaunch"
                    EnableViewState="false"
                    >
                    <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="QuickLaunchDataSource">







                        <Template_Controls>
                            <asp:SiteMapDataSource SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider" ShowStartingNode="False" id="QuickLaunchSiteMap" StartingNodeUrl="sid:1025" runat="server" />
                        </Template_Controls>
                    </SharePoint:DelegateControl>
                    <SharePoint:AspMenu id="V4QuickLaunchMenu" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" DataSourceId="QuickLaunchSiteMap" UseSimpleRendering="true" Orientation="Vertical" StaticDisplayLevels="1" AdjustForShowStartingNode="true" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="1" SkipLinkText="" />
                </SharePoint:SPNavigationManager>
                    <SharePoint:SPNavigationManager
                        id="TreeViewNavigationManagerV4"
                        runat="server"
                        ContainedControl="TreeView"
                        CssClass="ms-tv-box"
                    >
                        <SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx" id="idNavLinkSiteHierarchyV4" Text="<%$Resources:wss,treeview_header%>" accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_AK%>"
                        CssClass="ms-tv-header" />
                            <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="TreeViewAndDataSource">
                                <Template_Controls>
                                <SharePoint:SPHierarchyDataSourceControl
                                    runat="server"
                                    id="TreeViewDataSourceV4"
                                    RootContextObject="Web"
                                    IncludeDiscussionFolders="true"
                                />
                                <SharePoint:SPRememberScroll runat="server" id="TreeViewRememberScrollV4" onscroll="javascript:_spRecordScrollPositions(this);"
                                    style="overflow: auto;">
                                    <SharePoint:SPTreeView
                                    id="WebTreeViewV4"
                                    runat="server"
                                    ShowLines="true"
                                    DataSourceId="TreeViewDataSourceV4"
                                    ExpandDepth="0"
                                    ShowExpandCollapse="true"
                                    SelectedNodeStyle-CssClass="ms-tv-selected"
                                    NodeStyle-CssClass="ms-tv-item"
                                    SkipLinkText=""
                                    NodeIndent="12"
                                    ExpandImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/tvclosed.png?rev=23"
                                    ExpandImageUrlRtl="/_layouts/15/images/tvclosedrtl.png?rev=23"
                                    CollapseImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/tvopen.png?rev=23"
                                    CollapseImageUrlRtl="/_layouts/15/images/tvopenrtl.png?rev=23"
                                    NoExpandImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/tvblank.gif?rev=23"
                                    >
                                    </SharePoint:SPTreeView>
                                </SharePoint:SPRememberScroll>
                                </Template_Controls>
                            </SharePoint:DelegateControl>
                    </SharePoint:SPNavigationManager>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderQuickLaunchBottom" runat="server">
                    <div class="ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox">
                        <SharePoint:ClusteredSPLinkButton
                            runat="server"
                            id="idNavLinkViewAll"
                            PermissionsString="ViewFormPages"
                            NavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx"
                            Text="<%$Resources:wss,AllSiteContentMore%>"
                            accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_AK%>"
                            CssClass="ms-core-listMenu-item ms-core-listMenu-heading" />
                    </div>
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
</div>
<div id="contentBox"
 aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
  <div id="notificationArea" class="ms-notif-box"></div>
    <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPageStatusBar" BlockElement="true" runat="server">
        <div id="pageStatusBar"></div>
    </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
    <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderMain" BlockElement="true" IsMainContent="true" runat="server">
        <a id="mainContent" name="mainContent" tabindex="-1"></a>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server" />
    </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
</div>
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaFormDigest" BlockElement="true" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderFormDigest" runat="server">
        <SharePoint:FormDigest runat="server"/>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing/setting a different width for the web part in the web part properties?